# What do you mean by the statement :"Map is differentiable"?

Tags: calculus, terminology

The map $f(x)=a_{0} \cos |x|+a_{1} \sin |x|+a_{2}|x|^{3}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ if and only if
(A) $a_{1}=0$ and $a_{2}=0$
(B) $a_{0}=0$ and $a_{1}=0$
(C) $a_{1}=0$
(D) $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}$ can take any real value.

Comment: What is the end of your sentence? It isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry , I am trying to update

Answer (score 2):

All the summands are differentiable at $0$ with derivative $0$ except for the sine term. Setting $a_1=0$ removes this term and the function is differentiable.

Comment: sorry,but your comment is not clear to me.

Comment: The sine term is the only term that is not differentiable at $x=0$. We remove this term by setting $a_1=0$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\cos|x| = \cos x$ for any $x \in \Bbb R$ and thus, $\cos|x|$ is clearly differentiable at $x = 0.$

Now, using first principles, we can show that $|x|^3$ differentiable at $0$. Note that $|x|^3 = x^2|x|$ and thus,
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{|x|^3 - |0|^3}{x} = \lim_{x\to0}x|x| = 0.$$

This shows that $a_0\cos|x| + a_2|x|^3$ is differentiable at $0$ for any value of $a_0$ and $a_2$.

---

Now, suppose that $F = f_1 + f_2$ and $f_1$ is differentiable at $0$. Then, it is easy to see that $F$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if $f_2$ is. In our case, we can use the above to deduce that $f$ (as given in the question) is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $a_1\sin|x|$ is.

However, we note that $\sin|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$. This is because the following limit does not exist:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin|x|}{x}.$$
(To see that, let $x\to0^+$ and $x\to0^-$ and see that you get different results.)

This shows us that if $a_1 \neq 0$, then $a_1\sin|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$. It is obvious that if $a_1 = 0$, then it is indeed differentiable.

Thus, $a_1\sin|x|$ is differentiable at $0$ if and only if $a_1 = 0$.

---

To conclude, we get the answer as (C).

Comment: yes,it is clear now